# How can I generate sequenced Id values starting from 1, in Java Spring boot ? (Ex: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to store in my DB, a sequence of items, and I need the Ids to start from 1, like:

```
"data": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "item1",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "item2",
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "item3",
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "item4",
  },
],
```

I´m using MongoDB as my database

I tried a solution with the @Id Annotation, like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "author_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="author_generator", sequenceName = "author_seq", allocationSize = 1)
String id;
```

But it did not work at all

Comment: you can use @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Comment: since id in mongodb not support auto increase so i think you need a id generator

Comment: The best you can get https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-mongodb-auto-generated-field

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help, but try a for loop to get the numbers and convert the int to string for the IDs. (using coercion or explicit type)

Comment: I was thinking more of a @Id property solution, like:
`@Id
String id;
`